# How can I do some stuff after the save data to database immediately?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a WorkOrderCreateAPIView and WorkOrderCreateSerializer:

```
# views
class WorkOrderCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = WorkOrderCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = WorkOrder.objects.all()

# serializers
class WorkOrderCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    Create the work order
    """
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        exclude = ("workorder_num","to_group","user", "workorder_status")

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = getUserFormSerializer(self)
        to_group = Group.objects.filter(name=ADMIN_GROUP_CHOICES.售后组).first()

        return WorkOrder.objects.create(
            user=user,
            workorder_num = generateWorkorderNum(userid=user.id),
            to_group=to_group,
            workorder_status = WORKORDER_STATUS_CHOICES.已提交,
            **validated_data,
        )
```

I can access the `WorkOrderCreateAPIView` to create work order, but, I want to do some stuff after save the WorkOrder instance immediately.

You see, in the `create(self, validated_data)` method, the last line is `return WorkOrder.objects.create(xxx)`, it is not save data, so, how can I know when serializer or view save data? and after save data to database, I want to do some other things immediately, such as send email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save), but I believe it's not the only one way.